# Test if cells are blank using a formula and format to provide a fill color

Tags: excel

In cell P25 I have written the formula below to show an error message if any of the referenced cells are not blank. I actual found the <>"" to determine non blank cells from a answer to a question on this site

```
=IF(OR(D25<>"",H25<>"",L25<>0,T25<>0),"ERROR","")
```

the formula works but what I really want to do is select a fill color, probably red for the cell.

Comment: Use conditional formatting. Get there from `Home | Styles | Conditional Formatting | New Rule | Use a formula...` The test condition in your `IF` statement is the part you want in the `Rule Description`.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional formatting is the tool to use if you want to change the fill color of a cell based on the condition of other cells.

[image: Conditional formatting New Rule dialogue]

To test if:

- D25 & H25 are not a zero length strings and
- L25 & T25 are not equal to 0
  enter this in the formula box

  =OR(D25<>"", H25<>"", L25<>0, T25<>)
  then to apply a red fill, click the Format... button and follow your nose.

BTW a **blank** cell, by definition, can not contain a formula even if that formula evaluates to `""` or `0`.

A cell containing a formula that returns a zero length string may **look blank** but it isn't.